# How to only append a certain part of a DOMParser result to a DocumentFragment element

Tags: javascript, domparser, documentfragment

I'm trying to append the html result of a DOMParser to a DocumentFragment which I then append to the body (after some load event).

Appending the **whole** DOMParser result works, however appending only the `body` part of the result fails.

```
response.text().then(function(text) {

  var content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
  var bodyPart = content.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
  var fragmentElement = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var tempElement = fragmentElement.appendChild(bodyPart.documentElement);

  console.log(tempElement)

})
```

What am I doing wrong? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call innerHTML, return as a node.

```
response.text().then(function(text) {

      var content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html"),
          bodyPart = content.body,
          fragmentElement = document.createDocumentFragment(),
          tempElement = fragmentElement.appendChild(bodyPart);

      console.log(tempElement)

    })
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Perfect!